# Unexpected mysql behavior when inserting new rows

Tags: mysql

I've got this query:

```
INSERT INTO series_measures (sensor_SID,dataset_SID,created_on) 
VALUES (841468,145,'2016-10-26 11:36:07'), ... ,(841505,145,'2016-10-26 11:36:07') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sensor_SID=VALUES(sensor_SID),dataset_SID=VALUES(dataset_SID),created_on=VALUES(created_on);
```

Two things that I don't understand are happening here:

**A. If (sensor_SID-dataset_SID) is already inserted:**

Error:

> Duplicate entry '145-841468' for key 'fk_series_meas_dataset_idx'

But `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should avoid that.

**B. If (sensor_SID-dataset_SID) is not inserted yet:**

Error:

> Duplicate entry '412870' for key 'PRIMARY'

`PRIMARY` is `SID`, which has auto-increment (see create statement below), so that makes no sense to me.

---

This is the create statement of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `series_measures` (
  `SID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensor_SID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dataset_SID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fk_series_meas_dataset_idx` (`dataset_SID`,`sensor_SID`),
  KEY `fk_series_meas_sensor_idx` (`sensor_SID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_series_meas_dataset` FOREIGN KEY (`dataset_SID`) REFERENCES `datasets` (`SID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_series_meas_sensor` FOREIGN KEY (`sensor_SID`) REFERENCES `sensors` (`SID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=412908 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

Comment: That username rings a bell...

Comment: @Chris I honestly don't know what you are talking about... is it Narcos (which I haven't watched)? Or did I do something wrong? You got me intrigued.

Comment: @XavierPeña yes! That's a funny coincidence! (ok, enough off-topic :-)